# Is there a way to add an index in a list of tuples/list?

Tags: python

Let's say I have a list of tuples

```
users = [('Ben', 13),
         ('Ana', 13),
         ('Max', 13)]
```

Where ('Ben', 13) will be 0 and ('Ana', 13) will be 1 ...

EDIT

I have a table from PySimpleGUI that displays a list of tuples. Selecting a row in the table returns the row index. I want to get the 'User ID' that is tied to the returned row index so I could make use of it in a delete query.

Here's the code:

```
import sys
import mysql.connector
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def connect():
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host='localhost',
        user='root',
        passwd='maning',
        database='usersdb'
    )
    return mydb

mydb = connect()
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM thesisdb.users")
data = mycursor.fetchall() #the list of tuples
headings = ['User ID', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Username', 'Password', 'Role']


layout = [[sg.Table(values=data, headings=headings, max_col_width=25,
                        auto_size_columns=True, bind_return_key=True, justification='right', num_rows=20, alternating_row_color='lightgreen', key='users')],
          [sg.Button('Read'), sg.Button('Double')],
          [sg.T('Read = read which rows are selected')],[sg.T('Double = double the amount of data in the table')]]

window = sg.Window('Table', grab_anywhere=False, resizable=True).Layout(layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.Read()
    rowIndex = values['users'] #the index of the selected row
    sg.Popup(index) #displays the index of the selected row
```

As far as I know, the table is only capable of returning the index of the selected row. That's why I asked if it's possible to add an index number for each tuple because I want to use `rowIndex` in getting the 'User ID' with the same index number of the selected row.

The delete query will hopefully be:

`mycursor.execute("DELETE FROM usersdb.users WHERE user_ID = '%s'" % (userID))`

Comment: Python's got your back, search for [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Comment: the `index` always exists in lists. You do not have to add anything. This is why `users[0]` returns `('Ben', 13)`. The `0` in the `[0]` is the index.

Comment: Something like `list(zip(users, range(len(users))))`?

Comment: @jpp: I believe `enumerate()` is not necessarily the answer to the OP's question. `zip()` could be the desired alternative.

Comment: @Maning, Great edit, I've reopened.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis You are right! I finally got it. I had to remove the brackets from the list and convert it to int so I could use it as a parameter in accessing the row.

Answer (score 3):

Comment of @Ev. Kounis was right! Each tuple in a list of tuples already has an index. The only thing left to do in order for the list to be usable as a parameter in getting the desired element of the selected row was to remove the brackets and convert it to int.

Here's the code:

```
raw = values['users']
x = str(raw).replace('[', '').replace(']', '')
r_index = int(x)
userID = data[r_index][0]
```